# Can't get the number of days between 2 months - specific case

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have few dates in this format: `31/08/13` and I'm getting tehm from an `xls` file

What I need to do is to get the previous month and to calculate the days betwen these dates. I really don't know what to do.

Here is what I have tried:

code edited*

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                                Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                                end.setTime(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
                                start.add(start.MONTH,-1);

                                Date startDate = start.getTime();
                                Date endDate = end.getTime();
                                long startTime = startDate.getTime();
                                long endTime = endDate.getTime();
                                long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
                                long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

                                if(diffDays < 0){
                                    System.out.println(Math.abs(diffDays));
                                }

                                DateFormat dateFormatw = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                                System.out.println("The difference between "+
                                  dateFormatw.format(startDate)+" and "+
                                  dateFormatw.format(endDate)+" is "+
                                  diffDays+" days.");
```

But it seems wrong. I really can't get my mind on it as I'm so tired. I lost too many hours on this without luck.

I'm trying to get the same date but one month ago and to calculate the days, between these 2 dates `endTime` and `startTime`

Please help me!

Comment: check out Joda time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: How is it going wrong? Exception? Error? Wrong output? Maybe you need to cast one of the division operands to double.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: Not that it solves anything bur instead of using `set(day,month,year)` with depreciated `date22.getYear()`, `date22.getMonth()`, `date22.getDay()` you can just use `setTime(date22)`.

Comment: @Pshemo ok, but how do I get the previous date of `row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue()` which is `31/08/13` in my case?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by previous date, but if you want to set calendar one month earlier you can just add `-1` month with `calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);`

Comment: :( I'm lost. No idea what to do.

Comment: @Loïc internally time zones shouldn't matter thus the assumption of 24 hour days should still be valid.

Comment: you said your date is in format `31/08/13` which means dd/MM/yy in your code you use `dd-MM-yy` i think thats causes you problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a `ProdCalendar` is, it's presumably something internal to your project. But the simple way to get the numbers of days between 2 dates, which is (I think) what you want, is this:

```
//First date
Date d1 = dateFormat.parse("31-10-13");

//Second date
Date d2 = dateFormat.parse("31-08-13");

//Interval:     
long intervalMs = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
long intervalDays = intervalMs/(1000*60*60*24);
```

In your code, `date22` is initialised just with `new date()` so it will be the current system time. You are comparing that (in a depracated way) to a date retrieved from the spreadsheet. I also notice that Calendar `cal` in this line near the start:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
```

Is not used again, so appears to be redundant.

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be, so you need to step back and think about what you want to achieve. Simple code is good code.

Comment: Basicaly I have this date `31/08/13` and I want to convert it to `31/07/13` and to calculate the days between these 2 dates. I made some changes on teh code and will edit my question in a minute. :)

Comment: Just a side note: you might want to use `Math.ceil( (double)intervalMs/(1000*60*60*24));`, unless partial days don't matter (e.g. is the difference between `2013-11-25 23:59` and `2013-11-26 00:01` a day or zero days?).

Comment: you can use roll on the month by -1 working with Calendar and not Date

Comment: `start.add(start.MONTH,-1);` will take a month off from the time the Calendar was set to. Since you had not previously given the Calendar a time, it will start from the current system time. Hence the result will be system time minus one month. Is that what you want?

Comment: Dividing by `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` is not the right way to convert milliseconds into days.  You will get into all sorts of trouble around the beginning of daylight savings time.  Not all days are 24 hours - so  if the first date is in winter and the second date is in summer, the result will be out by one.